# Отправка html-формы без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Я отправляю следующую форму на сервер Node:

```
<form id="test_form" action="http://localhost:8080/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="filetoupload"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Необходимо чтобы сервер получал то же самое, но при этом не происходила перезагрузка страницы, при отправке формы.
Как реализовать? В какую сторону копать?

Comment: Вам нужен ajax.

Comment: Да, но как при помощи Ajax'а отправить данные в запросе точно в таком же виде, что и в текущей реализации? Иначе запрос некорректно обрабатывается на сервере.
Не могу понять что получает сервер при отправке запроса

Comment: Используй `new FormData`

Comment: Отправлять в новое окно (`target="_blank"`) или `iframe`.
Ещё можно просто научить сервер отвечать кодом 204, тогда страница не перезагрузится

Answer (score 1):

```
<div>
  <input type="file" id="filetoupload"><br>
  <input type="button" id="button" value="button">
</div>

<script>
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
  var file = document.getElementById('filetoupload').files[0];
  if (file) upload(file);

  function upload(file) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "/upload", true);
    xhr.send(file);

    xhr.onload = xhr.onerror = function() {
      if (this.status == 200) {
        console.log('Файл загружен');
      } else {
        console.log("error " + this.status);
      }
    };      
  }
};
</script>
```

1. Вы определись - форму отправляете или файл?
2. Кодировка `multipart/formdata` существует в природе для того, чтобы в рамках одной формы отсылать разные типы данных - бинарные и текст. Но ей же не пользуются, потому что запрос нельзя проверить на межсайтовую атаку - токен не виден до декодирования.
3. AJAX отправляет данные потоком (stream), а не одним пакетом - соотвецно, принимать их надо посредством `createStreamWrite`.
4. Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: В данном виде на сервер отправляется форма? `<form id="test_form" action="localhost:8080/upload"; method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="filetoupload"><br><input type="submit"></form>` В таком виде сервер принимает запрос и все работает правильно. Возможно с помощью http-запроса отправить данные в таком же виде, в каком они уходят на сервер при наведенном мной примере?